# Read JSON returned by PHP in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I want to select some content from the database and return it to the javascript. There are several rows returned by the database. I tried this with JSON and also get a result, if I print it out. But if I want to convert the JSON string, there is always the error message below. (at the JSON.parse) So, I assume maybe an mistake while filling the array? Thanks in advance guys!

Javascript:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "./select_firsttracks.php",
  type: "post",
  success: function(resultset) {
    $("#erroroutput").html(resultset);

    var arr = JSON.parse("{" + resultset + "}"); // --> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"            
  },
  error: function(output) {
    $("#erroroutput").html("fatal error while fetching tracks from db: " + output);
  }
});
```

PHP:

```
$storage = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $storage[] = 
        array
        (
            "id" => $row["id"],
            "trackname" => $row["trackname"],
            "artist" => $row["artist"],
            "genre" => $row["genre"],
            "url" => $row["url"],
            "musicovideo" => $row["musicovideo"]
        );

    echo json_encode($storage);
}
```

Output on the console:

```
[{"id":"1","trackname":"yes","artist":"Lady Gaga","genre":"Pop","url":"ftp:\/development","musicovideo":"1"}][{"id":"1","trackname":"yes","artist":"Lady Gaga","genre":"Pop","url":"ftp:\/development","musicovideo":"1"},{"id":"2","trackname":"no","artist":"Prinz Pi","genre":"Rap","url":"ftp:\/development","musicovideo":"1"}]
```

Comment: Your resultset already is a valid JSON; adding braces makes it bad.

Comment: Don't need to concat `{` and `}` in `JSON.parse("{" + resultset + "}");` **Code:** `JSON.parse(resultset);` or add `dataType: 'json',` in ajax configurations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

echo the json after the while

```
$storage = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $storage[] = 
        array
        (
            "id" => $row["id"],
            "trackname" => $row["trackname"],
            "artist" => $row["artist"],
            "genre" => $row["genre"],
            "url" => $row["url"],
            "musicovideo" => $row["musicovideo"]
        );


}
echo json_encode($storage);
```

and change:

```
 var arr = JSON.parse(resultset);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're adding curly braces in front and behind your received JSON, here:

```
var arr = JSON.parse("{" + resultset + "}");
```

Phps `json_encode` returns perfectly valid JSON by itself. Try it without adding the braces:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(resultset);
```

Answer (score 1):

The resulting `json` string is not valid, you can check it with [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Modify your php code to `echo` outside the loop:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $storage[] = 
        array
        (
            "id" => $row["id"],
            "trackname" => $row["trackname"],
            "artist" => $row["artist"],
            "genre" => $row["genre"],
            "url" => $row["url"],
            "musicovideo" => $row["musicovideo"]
        );


}
echo json_encode($storage);
```

And in javascript just use the output as a javascript object

```
success: function(resultset) {
    console.log(resultset)
    resultset.each(function(index,element){ console.log(index,element )})
  },
```